# Nested Package.json Storybook with Parcel

Tags: storybook, parceljs

I am looking for a way use storybooks parcel-preview in a sub-package of my main project.
The goal is to have storybook as a dependency only within the storybook folder.

The structure would be:

```
storybook/
  package.json
src/
package.json
```

storybook/package.json:
[main package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHilu.png)

scripts in ~/package.json:
[nested package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1C6k.png)

The issue that I am running into however, is that storybook is not inheriting the dependencies of the main project, and I am receiving errors like this:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHiwZ.png)